# How to pass the javascript varible to data-email in script tag

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

```
<script>
var email = $('#uemail').val();
print email;
</script>
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
data-name="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"
data-email=document.write(email);
data-description="<?php echo $row['desc'];?>"
data-amount="<?php echo $amount;?>"
data-label="Register" >
</script>
```

Here i want to pass the email value to data-email. I tried the above code but it is not working.

Any one suggest me how to assign the javascript value to the data-email

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your jQuery in a $(document).ready function and then append the fragment manually.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var email = $('#uemail').val();

  var scriptHtml = '<script '  +
    'src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" ' +
    'data-key="pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"' +
    'data-name="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" ' +
    'data-email="' + email + '" ' +
    'data-description="<?php echo $row['desc'];?>" ' +
    'data-amount="<?php echo $amount;?>" ' +
    'data-label="Register" >' +
    '</script>';

  //console.log(scriptHtml);
  $('head').append(scriptHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you're miss copied it.  and its after register.

Why are you document.writing it? document.write have no return value, just do

```
data-email=email;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding I tried this way also but showing email;  not exact email

Answer (score -1):

After the script:

```
$('script.stripe-button').data('email',email);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding . I think your code is works but i did any mistake by placing the code please once check my code  
                   <script
                    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button">  ------------------ </script>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                     $('script.stripe-button').data('email',email);
                  </script>

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.